# rails processing question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, process

I'm pretty new to rails and I got this error.
what does this mean:

```
Processing by ExamplesController#update as */*
```

mean?
Does this message prevent the update action in ExamplesController from running?

Answer (score 1):

When an HTTP request is made it specifies the `Accept` header to specify what format it would like the response to be. Rails will attempt to honor this via the `respond_to` construct. Additionally, Rails supports the ability to specify the desired response format via the url, by appending `.json` to a URL for instance.

For a generic HTTP request most HTTP clients will specify an `Accept: */*` which is what you are seeing in the `Processing` line. If you had specified either `Accept: application/json` or `http://foo.com/bar.json` then you'd see something like:

`Processing by ExamplesController#update as JSON`